# How to find a class in a list of classes using an internal variable C#/Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

simplified version

```
class item : ScriptableObject{
string name
//other things
public string GetName(){
return name;
}
}

class Main{
[SerializeField] list<item> List; //with inspector add like 15 different items

public item ItemReference(string name){
return List.find(name => name.GetName().Equals(name));
}
}
```

my issue here is that the function ItemReference does not return item

I have tried other methods like contains to see if the name => name.getName().equals(name) would work and that even did not work

Comment: Try renaming your lambda parameter so it is different from your method parameter, otherwise `item.GetName().Equals(item)` will always be false.

Answer (score 1):

Look closely at

```
public item ItemReference(string name)
{
    return List.Find(name => name.GetName().Equals(name));
    //               ^       ^                     ^
    //               |       |                     |
    //               -------------------------------
    //                        all the same
}
```

The `name` iterator of the lambda expression **hides** your method parameter `name`!

It should rather be e.g.

```
public item ItemReference(string name)
{
    // again confusing tbh as your class type is also lower case
    // according to c# conventions your class name should rather be Item so the difference would also be clear
    return List.Find(item => item.GetName().Equals(name));
}
```

---

Please look into [coding conventions regarding casing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/identifier-names). And please start to use a decent IDE for coding which should already warn you about

- your iterator variable hiding the method parameter
- your `Equals` check being doomed to always fail as `Item` will course never match `Item.name` (*except you have some very specific extension method implementation of `string.Equals(Item)`*)

assuming all the other casing issues in your provided code are only here and correct at your actual code (like e.g. `list`->`List` and `find`->`Find`)